# PHP Imagick create GIF animation

Tags: php, animation, imagick

I have some JPEG files and I want to create a GIF animation with them. However this code doesn't work. Can you see what the problem is?

```
// animation
$animation = new Imagick();
$animation->setFormat("GIF");

// frames
foreach($tmpJpegPath as $jpepPath) {
    $frame = new Imagick($jpepPath);
    $frame->thumbnailImage(176, 144);
    $animation->addImage($frame);
    $animation->setImageDelay(100);
    $animation->nextImage();
}

// save gif animation
$animation->writeImages('./animation.gif', true);
```

Comment: Sure it has jpeg support built in out of the box?  How exactly does it "not work"?  Errors?

Comment: @ficuscr if your mean is $jpepPath is a path for my jpeg files. thats right.

Comment: problem solved ... imagick must be >= 3.1.0RC1

Comment: @sweb, please post that as an actual answer, then mark it as accepted.  This will help future people that might encounter this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved ... imagick must be >= 3.1.0RC1

Comment: Don't forget to tick this answer `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with latest php5-imagick package on debian wheezy.

**My solution:**

for sure we remove package

```
apt-get remove php5-imagick
```

this is needed for next step

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

install imagick from pecl

```
pecl install imagick
echo "extension=imagick.so" >> /path/to/your/php.ini
```

done